# ASP.NET MVC . How to display test instead of id in view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view (Index) which display data from a model (TBL_PROJECT).

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_YEAR)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_STATUS)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

When displayed it would be: 
1998 Paint  1
1998 Cleaning 1

I need the status to be in text, which is in another model(TBL_STATUS). 
 What should I do?
This is the TBL_STATUS Model

```
public class TBL_STATUS
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string Query = null)
{
    var projectList = db.TBL_PROJECTS.Include(x => x.TBL_STATUS).Where(x => x.PROJ_CAT == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
    {
        projectList = projectList
            .Where(x => x.PROJ_NAME.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()))
            .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
    }
    return View(new PagedList.PagedList<TBL_PROJECT>(projectList, page, 10));
}
```

Update: I found out a way the way to do it. In the model (TBL_PROJECT) I add this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Current Status")]
    public int PROJ_STATUS { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PROJ_STATUS")]
    public TBL_STATUS TBL_STATUS { get; set; }
```

and when calling it in the View:...

```
 <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.TBL_STATUS.STATUS)
 </td>
```

Now I have another issue. Same issue, I want to add a district (which is an int in the TBL_PROJECT which refer to another model (TBL_DISTRICT)).

```
    public class TBL_DISTRICT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DIST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string DIST_OFFICE { get; set; }
    public string DIST_CODE { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my TBL_PROJECT model, I add these:

```
    [Display(Name = "District")]
    public int DISTRICT { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DISTRICT")]
    public TBL_DISTRICT TBL_DISTRICT { get; set; }
```

And in the view:

@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.TBL_DISTRICT.DIST_NAME )

Theres no error but it returned nothing. Do I need to add constraint between these tables (TBL_PROJECT & TBL_DISTRICT)?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using of View Models: http://wildermuth.com/2015/7/22/Mapping_Between_Entities_and_View_Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I put this first line in the controller.

```
var projectList = db.TBL_PROJECTS.Include(x => x.TBL_STATUS).Include(x => x.TBL_DISTRICT).Where(x => x.PROJ_CAT == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
```

I just add another Include(x => x.TableName)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in TBL_PROJECT Model.

```
public class TBL_PROJECT
{
//Code you have
public virtual TBL_STATUS TBL { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_YEAR.STATUS)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_NAME)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.TBL.STATUS)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use foreign key reference.

For reference:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score -1):

Use `@Html.Display(item.PROJ_STATUS.ToString())`